# How to turn this HTML code into a shortcode? (adding song lyrics and giving an id to a div)

Tags: shortcode

STEPS:

1. Don't forget to use different id numbers in each accordion. For example: id="5" (1 to 10)
2. The title goes between the
3. The lyrics before the
4. Place 2 accordions per posts (like the example below). Or they will mess up.

   ```
               <div class="basic" style="float:left;" id="5">
                   <a>There is one obvious advantage:</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           You've seen it coming!<br/>
                           Buy now and get nothing for free!<br/>

                           Well, at least no free beer. Perhaps a bear,<br/>
                           if you can afford it.
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <a>Now that you've got...</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           your bear, you have to admit it!<br/>

                           No, we aren't selling bears.
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <a>Rent one bear, ...</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           get two for three beer.
                       </p>
                       <p>

                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>

                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           Period.
                       </p>
                   </div>
           </div>

           <div class="basic" style="float:left;" id="6">
                   <a>There is one obvious advantage:</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           You've seen it coming!<br/>
                           Buy now and get nothing for free!<br/>

                           Well, at least no free beer. Perhaps a bear,<br/>
                           if you can afford it.
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <a>Now that you've got...</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           your bear, you have to admit it!<br/>

                           No, we aren't selling bears.
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <a>Rent one bear, ...</a>
                   <div>
                       <p>
                           get two for three beer.
                       </p>
                       <p>

                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>

                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           And now, for something completely different.<br/>
                           Period.
                       </p>
                   </div>
           </div>
   ```

My client said is too complicated. How can I turn this into a shortcode?

**EDIT**

This is a jQuery accordion the title goes in the anchor tags and the lyrics before the break tags and the ID of the divs have to change eacdh time.

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is likely to be possible using a plugin to handle the shortcode.  However, I cannot work out from what you've posted what you're trying to achieve.

Can you be a bit more detailed in what you're trying to achieve?  Rather than giving us the desired outcome, a bit of information on how to get there might be more useful.

Dave

Comment: this should really be a comments and not an answer!!

Comment: Forgive me, I realise that now.
However, I must be missing something as I cannot see a 'comment' link against the original post.

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

i think the shortcode ultimate plugin already handles accordian shortcodes.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/

if not maybe this one does:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/j-shortcodes/